# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (from <!DOCTYPE html>)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Im getting this weird error thats pointing to my  declaration and can not figure out how to fix it.

So initially, I was creating a small project to help me learn web development. I had initially started this project as a static web page but decided to connect it to a server because I needed to use a npm api package (yelp-node). Here is my server-side code that reads my html file.

https://jsfiddle.net/hgcm3w27/

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var verifyMimeType = true;
var port = 8000;
var serverURL = "127.0.0.1";

console.log("Starting web server: " + serverURL + ":" + port);

var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
  // set to URL or default to index.html
  var filename = "/index.html"
  console.log("Filename is: " + filename);
  // sets the extention of the filename
  var ext = path.extname(filename);
  var localPath = __dirname;
  console.log("Local path: "+ localPath);
  var validExtentions ={
    ".html" : "text/html",
    ".js": "application/javascript",
    ".css": "text/css",
    ".txt": "text/plain",
    ".jpg": "image/jpeg",
    ".gif": "image/gif",
    ".png": "image/png"
  };

  var validMimeType = true;
  var mimeType = validExtentions[ext];
  if(verifyMimeType){
    validMimeType = validExtentions[ext] != undefined;
  }

  if(validMimeType){
    localPath += filename;
    fs.exists(localPath, function(exists){
      if(exists){
        console.log("Serving file: " + localPath);
        getFile(localPath,res,mimeType);
      }
      else{
        console.log("File not found: " + localPath);
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
      }
    });
  }
  else{
    console.log("Invalid file extention detected: " + ext);
    console.log("Invalid file name: " + filename);
  }
});

server.listen(port,serverURL);

function getFile(localPath, res, mimeType){
  fs.readFile(localPath, function(err, data){
    if(err){
      console.log("Error with reading file: ("+ err + ")");
      res.writeHead(500);
      res.end();
    }
    else{
      res.setHeader("Content-Length", data.length);
      if(mimeType != undefined){
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", mimeType);
      }
      res.statusCode = 200;
      // the end does two things, it write to the response and
      // ends the response.
      res.end(data);
    }
  });
}
```

HTML file that its complaining about:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>En Route App.</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
   ....
```

It reads the file and connects to the server properly, but once I did that it is giving me this weird error. A bit confused because its saying that my scripts.js and yelp.js code is an html document in the console log but isnt. 
[image: script.js is the file that contains google map api]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `filename` being served is the same for every request. It's only being set once and to a hard-coded value.

```
var filename = "/index.html"
```

In the console output from your application, you should be seeing this for each request:

```
Filename is: /index.html
```

---

You can retrieve the path that's being requested from [`req.url`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/http.html#http_message_url), getting [its `pathname`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost):

```
var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url);
var filename = url.resolve('/', parsedUrl.pathname);
```

(Using [`url.resolve()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/url.html#url_url_resolve_from_to) will help avoid any attempts to retrieve files from outside of your application's public folder by adding multiple `../` to the path.)

---

To also support serving default files when the URL refers to a directory, you can check for a trailing slash:

```
// if requesting a directory, add a default file
if (/[\/\\]$/.test(filename)) {
    filename = url.resolve(filename, 'index.html');
}
```

Or, once you know the full disk path, you can check if it's a directory on disk with [`fs.stats()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) and [`stats.isDirectory()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats), then use [`path.join()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) to append `index.html`.

Comment: That was it! Thank Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the close tag head, check this.

Comment: This is not the issue.  He is only returning the contents of index.html for every file requested, including scripts.js and yelp.js.

Comment: This was the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to put HTML in a .js file, the extension matters. In this case, you'll want to move the HTML you've written in scripts.js into a .html file as it is HTML code.

Comment: This is not the issue.  He is only returning the contents of index.html for every file requested, including scripts.js and yelp.js.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue on my codeigniter website localhost setup. I was able to solve this issue by changing the content of .htaccess file in root folder.

here is .htaccess code I used

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```